# Copy tables from an on-prem database to an azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps

I am quite new to Logic App. I tried to copy tables from an on-prem database to an azure sql  database. Everything is set up (Gateway,...). I tried to make a loop on the tables with the action **Foreach** but I get stucked with the **Insert row (V2)** action

[image]

When I run the Logic App, I obtain the error:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "A value must be provided for item. XXX,
  "error": {
    "message": "A value must be provided for item."
  },
  "source": "sql-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

I know from the [Insert Row V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#insert-row-(v2)) that I have to add an item (Parameter: Row) but I don't know how to add it from the dynamic content because it only shows when I click on "Body":

[image]

How can I add the item?

Comment: I forget to mention that I also have a "actionfailed. an action failed. no dependent actions succeeded." below the foreach control.

Comment: Are you restricted to use azure logic app only? because the task can be accomplished using azure data factory more efficiently.

Comment: Hello, yes. I have to use logic app because it's much less expensive than Azure Data Factory (self-hosted integration runtime is apparently very expensive). The tables should be quite small.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your table schema and the logic app model you are using ? So I can answer more precisely.

I assume you have only one column named 'Body' in your on-prem DB table. Make sure to configure in a way that the result has multiple rows ( in previous steps "GetRowsV2" action)

The outputs of GetRowsv2 operation are dynamic. Usually the default parameter "Value" contains complete result as seen below.
[image]

[image]

When the result content has more than one occurrence, it is automatically considered to be put inside "ForEach" action.

The value that do not match the field data types are not listed under dynamic content.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I finally found out how to solve it but I ended up with other problems. I am not gonna use Logic App for this task, too complex and not well suited.